# Image is not found error in MSChart Control

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, mschart

I have an application that relies heavily on charting and currently the charts will work in the ASP.Net Development Server, but when I try to publish out to my server (Win Server 2016 , IIS 8), the charts do not show up.

Using Firebug, I can see that the call to ChartImg.axd returns a 404, and all I get is a blank image holder in IE, or nothing in Firefox. I've searched for about 3 or 4 hours so far, and have tried just about everything recommended, but nothing seems to be working.

I would like to use  the ImageLocation configuration.

My Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" description="Menu SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap"/>
    <add name="AdminSiteMapPathProvider" description="Page Nav SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/xml/Admin_forSiteMapPath.sitemap"/>
    <add name="SecondEngSiteMapPathProvider" description="Page Nav SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/xml/SecondEng_forSiteMapPath.sitemap"/>
    <add name="FirstEngSiteMapPathProvider" description="Page Nav SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/xml/FirstEng_forSiteMapPath.sitemap"/>
    <add name="GigapopUserSiteMapPathProvider" description="Page Nav SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/xml/GigapopUser_forSiteMapPath.sitemap"/>
    <add name="TesterSiteMapPathProvider" description="Page Nav SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/xml/Tester_forSiteMapPath.sitemap"/>
  </providers>
</siteMap>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
     <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<authentication mode="Windows"/>

<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.aspx"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you